# How to use node:fs inside of a vue app to save images into source directory

Tags: node.js, vue.js, file-storage

I'm building a personal portfolio website using Vue.js, and I'm attempting to build a form to allow me to add to my portfolio later. I'm storing the text data in firebase, but I also want to be able to upload and access pictures. I'm attempting to upload through a form and save with node:fs with the following
`import { writeFile } from 'node:fs'`

```
export function saveImages (data:FileList, toDoc: string) {
  const reader = new FileReader()
  const imageNames = []
  console.log(toDoc)
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    imageNames.push(toDoc + '/' + data[i].name)
    reader.readAsBinaryString(data[i])
    reader.onloadend = function (e) {
      if (e.target?.readyState === FileReader.DONE) {
        const imageFile = e.target.result as string
        if (imageFile) {
          writeFile('./assets/' + data[i].name, imageFile, 'binary', (err) =>
            console.log('was unable to save file ' + data[i].name + ' => ' + err)
          )
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return imageNames
}
```

When I attempt to call saveImages, I get the error

```
ERROR in node:fs

Module build failed: UnhandledSchemeError: Reading from "node:fs" is not handled by plugins (Unhandled scheme).
Webpack supports "data:" and "file:" URIs by default.
You may need an additional plugin to handle "node:" URIs.
```

Comment: You can't use `fs` inside a Vue app. `fs` is a NodeJS module.

Comment: to expand on the above. vuejs runs on the browser, nodejs does not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by the comments on your answer, the Node.js-`fs`-module is cannot be used in the frontend. Here is why:

1. While developing your `vue.js`-app, you should remember that you always have to run a development server in order for the app to compile to a browser-readable format. The resulting page will not be delivered as some `.vue`-files and `.js`-files but everything will be bundled into an `html`-file and some additional `.js`-files.
2. While running the development server, the source directory of your app is 'lying' on a server, but this is not even the directory that is delivered to the browser.
3. In a production server, there will be static assets built out for your `vue.js`-app, which does also only contain `.html`- and `.js`-files.
4. When a client (browser) accesses a route, some static files will be delivered to the browser, and all the code you are writing in your `.vue`-files will be run on the client's machine, not on a server. So you cannot interact with server-side directories.

Therefore, you should look into a backend server framework, which you can connect to your frontend to allow users to upload files to a server, and those files would be saved on the server. You will then set up your vue app to communicate with the backend. Here are some additional resources:

- [Node modules with vue: StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43884980/node-modules-with-vue-cli)
- [Express.js: popular backend framework for Node.js](https://expressjs.com/)
- [Express.js: Deliver files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691194/node-express-file-upload)
- [Blog article on Express.js file upload (Attacomsian)](https://attacomsian.com/blog/uploading-files-nodejs-express)
- You might also want to take a look on how to send [static files with express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html), because once the files are uploaded and the server receives them, it could store them into a `static`-directory, where you could access them without having to use separate API-routes.

Comment: Thank you for the insight!! That helps a lot I am obviously new to building apps with Vue.

Comment: If it answered your question, I would be grateful if you marked my solution as "accepted"; it is a good practice on StackOverflow so others can easily detect "right" answers when viewing your question :)